# Render array of objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a method in a React component which fetches some data from an API

this.state.matches returns an empty array at first

```
loadMatches() {
    let matches = this.state.matches;
    forEach(this.state.matchIds.splice(0,5), matchid => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                matches.push(response.data)
            })
    });
    this.setState({
        matches
    })
}
```

And then a method which should map the data to React components

```
renderMatch() {
    return this.state.matches.map((match, index) => {
        return (
            <Match
                key={index}
                gameId={match.gameId}
            />
        );
    });
}
```

renderMatch() is called in my render method with `{this.renderMatch()}`
But nothing is getting rendered and if i call .length it just returns 0 even though i can see in devtools that the array contains 5 objects.
Hardcoded objects in the array gets rendered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mutating the state so React doesn't trigger a new render. You should create a new array instead of pushing in the state :

```
loadMatches() {
    let promises = []; 
    forEach(this.state.matchIds.splice(0,5), matchid => {
        promises.push(axios.get(url).then(res => res.data));
    });
    Promise.all(promises).then(matches => {
        this.setState({
            matches
        });
   });
}
```

Edited to handle the async.

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems:

First:

```
.then(function (response) {
   matches.push(response.data)
})
```

You should not change state directly, you should perform immutable update.

Second:

```
this.setState({
   matches
})
```

You are updating state with empty 'matches', at this point your api call's responses are not received yet.

So, your implementation should look like this:

```
loadMatches() {
let matches = this.state.matches;
forEach(this.state.matchIds.splice(0,5), matchid => {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function (response) {
            const newMatch = response.data;
            this.setState({ matches: [...matches, newMatch]});
            matches.push(response.data)
        })
});
}
```

Here some sources that you can also benefit from reading them:

https://daveceddia.com/immutable-updates-react-redux/

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

axios or fetch is an async function, there for when you call `this.setState` matches is still an empty array, hence nothing is rendered. try this instead. also you are trying to mutate the state directly which is a big mistake.

```
loadMatches() {
 let matches = this.state.matches;
let newMatches =[];
let requests = forEach(this.state.matchIds.splice(0,5), matchid => {
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
         axios.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
               newMatches.push(response.data)
           })
      });
    });
   Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
     this.setState({
         matches:newMatches
       }) 

    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`axios.get` is an asynchronous function which returns a `promise`. Its like you've ordered a pizza and trying to eat it before it gets delivered. You need to perform the `setState()` when you resolve the promise.

```
axios.get(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({matches: [...matches, ...response.data]})
               }
```